# What is purpose of anorm's Pk?

Tags: scala, types, playframework-2.0, anorm

I'm writing Playframework 2.0 application using Scala and Anorm to access db.

Currently I'm using `Pk[Long]` for `id` fields and I'm worry about additional `get` call needed to access actual value. So I start using plain `Long` for `id` fields and everything still work perfect.

What `Pk` is for, and should I use it instead of plain types? Does `Pk` gives me additional features/benefits over plain types?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Pk` allows you to specify a typed primary key.

Also, say you have a contrived model like this:

```
case class MyModel(id: Pk[Long], foo: String)
```

You have the benefit of constructing an instance of your model with:

```
MyModel(anorm.NotAssigned, "notKnownAtRuntime")
```

...if your database is responsible for generating your keys, or otherwise:

```
MyModel(anorm.Id(123L), "knownAtRuntime")
```

Comment: I know about `NotAssigned`, it is handy, since id generates automatically. I just thought there is something else. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Why not using `Option[Long]` and then initialize your Objects with `None` or `Some(123L)`?

Comment: @mklemenz because ```case class MyModel(id: Pk[Long], id2: Pk[Long])``` should not compile where ```case class MyModel(id: Option[Long], id2: Option[Long])``` compiles