# "email:Pk[String]" vs "id:Pk[Long]"

Tags: scala, playframework

In some examples, I'm seeing `email:Pk[String]` under the `User` class but in others I see `id:Pk[Long]` (both not assigned). A user can change their email as much as they want but the ID will not change so **is there a (security) reason behind this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if your question refers to `NotAssigned` or `email:Pk[String]`, but to an answer both: not really. This SO post discusses the uses of `Pk`: [What is purpose of anorm's Pk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168222/what-is-purpose-of-anorms-pk)

The purpose of something like `case class User(id:Pk[Long] = NotAssigned, name:String)` with the id being `NotAssigned` by default allows for a representation of a model that hasn't been persisted in the database yet. The id can later be filled in after saving.

I'm not sure why you would ever want `email: Pk[String] = NotAssigned`, as a user's email is a critical piece of information when persisting the model. Though it is certainly fine to use the email address as the primary key if you really don't care (or have) ids. Email addresses should at **at least** be set as a unique key in the database, anyway, since it should never be possible for two users to have the same email.

Comment: Note that as of Play 2.3.0, `Pk[A]` is deprecated, and `Option[A]` should be used instead.